# How to control scene in the unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am the rookie of the unity2d... I hope some guys can teach me and give me some hints about the title. How to control the scene and how to use the trigger. I really hope someone can teach me.

Comment: I recommend some videos by Brackeys, BlackThornProd, CodeMonkey, and SpeedTutor, try looking it up on YouTube. Maybe this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcFtoiWZ86w. Or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc9lmHjqLZc

Comment: thanks you very much!

Comment: No problem! Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sorry I still can't fixed my problem... Can I chat with you in private?